# Incorrect HitTest on resizing a DevExpress XtraGrid column

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid, mousedown, mouseup

Custom sorting and column resize does not work.

Implemented custom sorting on MouseUp event handler however

```
if ( hitInfo.InColumnPanel && hitInfo.HitTest == GridHitTest.ColumnEdge)
{
   (e as DXMouseEventArgs).Handled = true;
    return;
}
```

does not work for the event.

Would like to be able to click on the column header to sort and resize by dragging  column edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   GridHitInfo hitInfo = gridView1.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);
   if (hitInfo.HitTest == GridHitTest.ColumnEdge)
   {
      isEdgeClicked = true;
   }
}

private void OnMouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) 
{
   if (isEdgeClicked)
   {   isEdgeClicked = false;
       return;
   }
   else 
   {
      (e as DXMouseEventArgs).Handled = true;
   }
}
```